# LibreOffice: how to get it to use the window manager's file browser?

Tags: libreoffice, file-manager

I think I asked that some years ago, but cannot find it anymore.

I just upgraded to Fedora 36 and since then, my LibreOffice uses its own inbuilt file browser again, rather than Gnome's nautilus.

The question is: where in LibreOffice can I configure it to use the window manager's default file browser/manager?

Comment: In my old (v7.1.5) LibreOffice running on Kubuntu 20.04, `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > General > Open/Save Dialogs` is unchecked and so a "KDE"-type window opens for saving/opening operations.

Comment: dear @DKBose, add that as an answer and I will accept. that was it! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On
LibreOffice Version: 7.3.4.2 this works, as indicated by @DK Bose in a comment to the question.

`Tools > Options > LibreOffice > General > Open/Save Dialoge` uncheck the checkbox at `Use LibreOffice dialogs`

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice is a standalone program, it does not use `nautilus` or any other file browser.  It has its own File Open & File Save dialog boxes.

It does, however, have several options for integrating with particular window managers / desktop environments / GUI libraries.  It has integration packages for generic gtk3, KDE frameworks, KDE plasma, generic qt5....AND one for Gnome so that LO's dialog boxes and GUI widgets etc look and feel and work like those in any other Gnome application.

I don't know what LO's gnome integration package is called on Fedora 36, but on Debian it is `libreoffice-gnome`.  Look for a similarly-named package on Fedora and install that.